# MySQL Database Schema recommendations?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

[image]

Hello, all! I have several needs that I'm attempting to accomplish with my database implementation.

1. List number of wins / losses for a particular user
2. Keep track of the amount of coins a user has
3. Allow user to purchase items from a shop
4. List profitability from all gambling-based games

For my use case, I have several games the end user can play. The "Fun" category of games does not award 'coins'; however, I want users to be able to list how many they've won. All the gambling-based games allow players to earn / lose their 'coins' when playing.

- Fun Games:

  - Rock, Paper, Scissors
  - Connect Four
  - TicTacToe
- Gambling Games

  - Slot Machine (Slots)
  - Black Jack
  - HiLo
  - Coin Flip

After doing some research online, I have implemented a 'match' table to keep track of all the matches between players. With two player game sessions, two rows will be created. If I want to know how many wins a player has, I can use a sum(wins) from the match table. Additionally, from the 'gambling' match table, I can run a similar query to pull the profitability loss / gain. Is there a better way of doing this?

Additionally, if a user profited from a gambling match - I'm assuming I'd need to perform two operations:

- Add new row in GamblingMatch
- Update amount of coins a player has

At this moment, I'm not sure of a way to do that in one operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are fine.

To combine multiple row insert/updates/deletes together, use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).